# Why is the output of a sequelize promise different when parsed

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have some promise code that looks like this.

```
let residences = await DB.findAll(...);
```

So I make it wait to fulfill the sequelize promise and then I print some stuff that looks like a promise.

```
console.log(residences);
[ { dataValues: 
 { id: 1,
   address: '6509 Pardall Rd',
   city: 'Goleta',
   state: 'CA',
   zipcode: '93117',
   user_id: 4,
   category: 'apartment',
   amenities: null,
   created_at: Wed Mar 09 2016 22:26:09 GMT-0800 (PST),
   updated_at: Wed Mar 09 2016 22:26:09 GMT-0800 (PST),
   room_count: '1',
   'room_types.name': 'living' },
_previousDataValues: 
 { id: 1,
   address: '6509 Pardall Rd',
   city: 'Goleta',
   state: 'CA',
   zipcode: '93117',
   user_id: 4,
   category: 'apartment',
   amenities: null,
   created_at: Wed Mar 09 2016 22:26:09 GMT-0800 (PST),
   updated_at: Wed Mar 09 2016 22:26:09 GMT-0800 (PST),
   room_count: '1',
   'room_types.name': 'living' },
_changed: {},
'$modelOptions': 
 { timestamps: true,
   instanceMethods: {},
   classMethods: {},
   validate: {},
   freezeTableName: false,
   underscored: true,
   underscoredAll: false,
   paranoid: false,
   whereCollection: null,
   schema: null,
   schemaDelimiter: '',
   defaultScope: {},
   scopes: [],
   hooks: {},
   indexes: [],
   name: [Object],
   omitNull: true,
   sequelize: [Object],
   uniqueKeys: {},
   hasPrimaryKeys: true },
'$options': 
 { isNewRecord: false,
   '$schema': null,
   '$schemaDelimiter': '',
......
```

But if I parse the object, I get what I would expect the promise to return.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(residences));
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "address": "6509 Pardall Rd",
    "city": "Goleta",
    "state": "CA",
    "zipcode": "93117",
    "user_id": 4,
    "category": "apartment",
    "amenities": null,
    "created_at": "2016-03-10T06:26:09.091Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-03-10T06:26:09.091Z",
    "room_count": "1",
    "room_types.name": "living"
  }
]
```

Why do these two print lines output such drastically different text?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` prints the complete structure of the object provided as in your case. But the `JSON.stringify()` function ignores all non-enumerable keys. For detailed description go to
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
hope it helped

Comment: To further elaborate - in the first case you are printing sequelize instances - the things that have lots of methods for updating, deleting instances and so on. But when you stringify, that calls the `toJSON` method (also a method on the sequelize instance prototype), which returns only the attributes defined in the table